# Semantic result format Oltree - result getting distorted when number of query results get larger than 50

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am using the oltree format (Semantic result format) to view a hierarchically linked data. The tree is ordered using a semantic property called Order and is filtered using a semantic property called Type.

The query is working fine and getting an ordered tree. But when the number of results get larger, the tree get distorted and some of the results are not shown. We did an analysis and found that this is happening when the number of results are more than 50 .

Following is the sample query

```
 {{#ask: [[Category:Sample]][[Parent::+]][[Type::New]] |?Business Objective= |   
 format=oltree | parent=Parent | sort=Order | order=ASC }}
```

**Environment**

1. MediaWiki   1.21.2
2. Semantic MediaWiki (Version 1.8.0.5)
3. Semantic Result Formats (Version 1.8)

Did anybody came across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might simply be because the default limit of the number of returned for that result format is 50. Try adding e.g. `|limit=500` to your query to more results.

To be able to use limits > 500, you need to raise `$smwgQMaxInlineLimit` in your LocalSettings.php to something higher, e.g. 2000.

Comment: Thank you Leo,
It worked for me.
A bad miss from me while reading the documentation